# Is there a rtl-sdr wrapper for the funcube dongle?

Tags: software-defined-radio, software, rtl-sdr

I would like to use some software packages, such as rtl_433, that are written with the RTL-SDR library with a FUNcube Dongle instead.
Is there a wrapper that would allow the FUNcube Dongle to be used with RTL-SDR?

Comment: I expect the answer is “no”.

Answer (score 2):

The librtlsdr is for RTL2832U based DVB-T dongles.  The Funcube Dongle has no RTL2832U chip. However, the overarching OSMOSDR project includes support for the Funcube Dongles (Pro and Pro+) and other SDR equipment. See http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/GrOsmoSDR for more information.